# How to find strings

Tags: r

I have a df as below

df:

```
Name               |Code
-------------------+-----
aman               |abc
akash              |bcd
rudra              |cde
Tushar             |def
Kartik             |efg
aman,akash         |fgh
akash,rudra        |ghi
akash,rudra,aman   |ijk
aman,Tushar        |jkl
Kartik,Tushar      |klm
rudra,Kartik,akash |lmn
```

i want to search code for below df

```
Name            |
----------------+
aman,akash,rudra|
Tushar,aman     |
Kartik          |
rudra,akash     |
```

to get below result

```
Name            |code
----------------+-----
aman,akash,rudra|ijk
Tushar,aman     |jkl
Kartik          |efg
rudra,akash     |ghi
```

Please note that combo of "rudra,akash"occur three times, in that case it returns the result alphabatical order of code

let me know if there is some way to achieve this.

Comment: @RonakShah real set of data is very large. This is just a sample set...
so in previous question ,soution was resulting in getting all values of code for which name consists of "aman,akash,rudra"

here i want to get only first value of code wen arranged in alphabetical order

also, here i want to get answer for a large set of name combos then asked previously(2)

Comment: @akrun Why not? Looks pretty much the same to me

Comment: @Jaap it's not. Iam repeating myself again.. let me know if you need more claruication
In previous question ,soution was resulting in getting all values of code for which name consists of "aman,akash,rudra" here i want to get only first value of code wen arranged in alphabetical order also, here i want to get answer for a large set of name combos then asked previously(2)

Comment: @akrun You have the power to reopen. By not doing so, I looks to me that you also think it is a legitimate duplicate.

Comment: @akrun That is a false accusation. Why do you think so?

Comment: guys i am new to stackoverflow, and dont want to create any issue for anyone. stackoverflow is a wonderful platform for beginner like me.
Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: I'm willing to reopen, but then you will have to make clear how the selection has to be done. For example, you say that the combo `rudra,akash` occurs three times. Why does the code `ghi` need to be selected and not the other matches?

Comment: @Jaap thats the requirement to return the code which comes first in alphabetical order... the code for combo rudra,akash  are ghi,ijk,lmn... out of which ghi comes first. 
hence expected output is ghi

Comment: @aman I just posted a solution below.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to split the 'Name' column and reshape it to 'long' format ('dfN'), grouped by 'Code', and run-length-id of 'Code', we `paste` the 'Name' after `sort`ing.  Do the same with 'df2', `match` the 'Name' columns in both the dataset and get the 'Code' in 'dfN' that corresponds to create a new column 'code' in 'df2'

```
library(splitstackshape)
dfN <- cSplit(df, "Name", ",", "long")[, .(Name = paste(sort(Name), collapse=",")), 
             by =  .(grp = rleid(Code), Code)]
df2$grp <- seq_len(nrow(df2))
df2$code <-  cSplit(df2, "Name", ",", "long")[, .(Name = paste(sort(Name), 
     collapse=",")), .(grp)][, dfN$Code[match(Name, dfN$Name)]]
df2$grp <- NULL
df2
#              Name code
#1 aman,akash,rudra  ijk
#2      Tushar,aman  jkl
#3           Kartik  efg
#4      rudra,akash  ghi
```